# how to group similar names from database before "-"

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

hey so my database looks like this. Please only focus on the second column:
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0icI.jpg)

and for now i have done this that looks like:
[what i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7Rj.jpg)

so for now as u all can see i did a view where it shows and separates and groups the same value:

approval-timing-when,
approval-violation,
cancellation-person,
cancellation-person-1,
cancellation-person-2

but what i want to do now is to group all "approval" together and all "cancellation" together and not separate them as shown in my second pictuere. How can i do that? My code is as below:

route:

```html
Route::get('queries/{companyID}/{entityType}/{entityValue}','Chatbot\ChatbotController@queries');
```

controller:

```html
public function queries($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
{
  $data = [];

  $details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();

  foreach ($details AS $datum) 
  { 
    if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []]; 
    $data[$datum->intent]['question'][$datum->queries] = $datum->id; 
  } 

  $detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();

  foreach ($detailsAns AS $datum) 
  { 
    if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []]; 
    $data[$datum->intent]['answer'][$datum->reply] = $datum->id; 
  }

  ksort($data);
  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
}
```

view:

```html
@foreach($data as $intentName => $questionAnswer)
  <div class="form-group edit-response-container">
    <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{{$intentName}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{$intentName}}"> {{$intentName}} <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></label>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse-{{$intentName}}">

    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `groupBy` collection method and work off the second column like this:

```
// change to your model and whatever the second column is named.
$collection = Model::all();
// or DiraQuestion/DiraResponse ..
$collection = ... your query...
// then
$grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return explode('-', $item['column_2'])[0];
});
```

**update**

```
// result of DiraResponses query
$grouped = $detailsAns->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return explode('-', $item['column_2'])[0];
});
```

Comment: but how can i use that in my controller above?

Comment: Is the table with `approval` and `cancellation` for the `DiraResponse` model?

Comment: its for the DiraQuestion

Comment: but they both are the same so u could use either one

Comment: In that case you'd just use the result of those queries in place of `$collection`. I'll update my answer.